# where on each brick does LEGO put the branding and what do the identification markings on the underside look like?

Tags: piece-information, minifigures, clone-brands

I was given a mix of bricks which included bricks that have branding on the studs (Lego) as well as some other blocks. I was able to remove the bricks without branding as well as non-Lego bricks; however, the bricks with Lego studs don't all look like they are real.

I looked up text of Lego to compare for authenticity but results were rare. I have heard a about people selling "Lego bricks" that look so close the real ones and I can not tell the difference between them but I have a feeling that some or most of these might not be real. if I knew exactly what true Lego markings looked like, I would be able to get rid of the fakes. if I knew where the logo was printed and the style and sizes Lego used under the bricks it would give my collection more value.

Did Lego always have the branding inside the mini figure legs.

I know the letters and numbers inside Lego bricks are small but they should be able to be seen and read - is that correct? Please help so I can build a case against the companies I have been getting these bricks from so I can shut them down.

Comment: The word **bricks** means one thing, but sometimes people use it to mean *any* Lego piece, and I think perhaps you are doing that here. For Lego pieces (I almost wrote "authentic Lego pieces" but if they're not authentic, they're not Lego) the locations and fonts and font sizes have all changed over the years. I have seen one report of a company forging the word Lego on their bricks, but I am not convinced it was anything more nefarious than a bad manufacturing incident. Also, you say "printed", but the logos would have been molded, or stamped, not printed. To be continued...

Comment: Some pieces (like 1x1 round bricks and 1x1 round cones) have Lego markings on them on newly-produced pieces, but until recently, they did not. I have been pondering a question on here about what the most recent piece Lego makes isn't marked - I have not seen a Lego marking on any hot dog sausage piece I own, for instance. It took me a lot of effort to find them on the ice lolly, or Captain America's shield.

Comment: I think I used bricks as a way to indicate that the pieces are a variety or brands and yes the lego are molded as a technicality but I think that the location of the letters and numbers is what was in question because i have some suspected counterfeit bricks and I want to save the authentic for my collections

Comment: I have also spent a vast (**vast**) amount of time keeping Lego apart from imitation pieces, so I empathize with your plight.

Comment: Would you be able to post some macro shots of what you're seeing that makes you think it might be fake? It's very difficult to take clear photos of this unless you have the right equipment (which makes it easy).